# Laravel Session Flash not working on listener

Tags: php, laravel

I am running into an issue where I am trying to flash a message on screen from a listener in laravel, but for some reason it isn't displaying.

Here is the listener:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Assada\Achievements\Model\AchievementProgress;
use Assada\Achievements\Event\Unlocked;

class AchievementUnlocked
{

    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  Unlocked  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Unlocked $event)
    {
        // There's an AchievementProgress instance located on $event->progress
        session()->flash('achievement', $event->progress->details->name);
    }
}
```

Then on the app.blade.php

```
    @if (session()->has('achievement'))
        <div class="bg-teal-100 border-t-4 border-teal-500 rounded-b text-teal-900 px-4 py-3 shadow-md my-3" role="alert">
            <div class="flex">
              <div>
                  <p class="text-sm">{{ session('achievement') }}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      @endif
```

Am I missing something? Also can I listen for this event from a Livewire component instead or dispatch another event to a livewire component. Ideally I want to display a message on screen that a user unlocked an achievement and I am just looking for the best way to achieve it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
Session::put('achievement', $event->progress->details->name);
```

and import this in top `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;`

Comment: This works for getting it added to the session, but it only appears after page refresh as opposed to realtime. Is there a way I can get it to update realtime with out needing to refresh?

Comment: @Markwow did you find the solution? and do you remember it? thanks

Comment: @sunergos session only works on page load.. where you have face problem can you tell

Comment: @sunergos, I changed my approach so that it dispatches an event to pusher and the Livewire component listens for the event and displays information about the achievement based on what is returned from pusher. Hope this helps!